# Why is the time to resize operation of array proportional to N if done by repeated doubling?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, copy, time-complexity

If array is full and its size is increased by 1 to insert the new element, time to insert N elements can be calculated as 1+2+ .. N = N^2/2. (declare new array with length size+1 and copy the elements to the new array).

I am unable to understand how can one calculate the time if instead of increasing the array size by 1 we declare a new array with length 2*size and then copy the elements in the new array.

Comment: A [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) is relevant here. Assume N = 2^k for some k and write down the sum of costs to get to an array of length N starting from an array of length 1 by doubling its size at every expansion, then factor out N from that sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have an array of size 1 and this array will be doubling each time it becomes full.

Now, you are about to insert 2048 items: then, it will extend and copy contents when its length becomes `2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048`. In total, it will take take 4094 (~2n) operations.

Also, it will take `n` operations to simply insert items into arrays.

In sum, it is `O(n)`, linear.

It can be easily described by geometric series sum formula with coefficient `r = 2` and first item `a1 = 2`:

```
Sn = a1 * (r ^ n - 1) / (r - 1)
   = 2 * (2 ^ n - 1) / (2 - 1) 
   = 2 * 2 ^ n
```

where `n` is a count of array "doublings".

As doubling occurs on pows of 2, it will be, in general, close to `log2(n)`.

`2 * 2 ^ log2(n) = 2 * n`, which means that it is always linear.